# Inconsistent error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 30 column 2 (char 590)

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have .json documents generated from the same code. Here multiple nested dicts are being dumped to the json documents. While loadling with `json.load(opened_json)`, I get the `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 30 column 2 (char 590)` like error for some of of the files whereas not for others. It is not understood why. What is the proper way to dump multiple dicts (maybe nested) into json docs and in my current case what is way to read them all? (Extra: Dicts can be over multiple lines, so 'linesplitting' does not work probably.)

Ex: Say I am `json.dump(data, file)` with `data = {'meta_data':{some_data}, 'real_data':{more_data}}`.

Let us take these two fake files:

```
{
    "meta_data": {
        "id": 0,
        "start": 1238397024.0,
        "end": 1238397056.0,
        "best": []
    },
    "real_data": {
        "YAS": {
            "t1": [
                1238397047.2182617
            ],
            "v1": [
                5.0438767766574255
            ],
            "v2": [
                4.371670270544587
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "meta_data": {
        "id": 0,
        "start": 1238397056.0,
        "end": 1238397088.0,
        "best": []
    },
    "real_data": {
        "XAS": {
            "t1": [
                1238397047.2182617
            ],
            "v1": [
                5.0438767766574255
            ],
            "v2": [
                4.371670270544587
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and try to load them using `json.load(open(file_path))` for duplicatling the problem.

[image: The first file throws the error; copying and pasting however works fine]

Comment: [Tell us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) what happened. The details matter. Share the code you ran, the input data it consumed, and the diagnostic output it produced. If you want SO participants to help, it's important that they be able to reproduce your results. That means run the same code, on the same input data, and view the same output that you're seeing. Post a revised question, and then try to copy-n-paste from that question's text to verify that folks can reproduce the observed symptom.

Comment: Nested dictionary is not a problem while dumping. Please check the data if you have some missing quote, comma, parenthesis and etc.

Comment: Hi @bonifacio_kid, the data are generated from same code!

Comment: This is still not reproducible. `json.loads()` will load both of those as a triple quoted string.

Comment: Yeah! Let me try again :(

Comment: I post my answer bellow.

Comment: I am copying and pasting the erroneous code here, somehow when we take from SO it works! Why does it happen? But that is what I could do. Is there a way I can put the file here..

Comment: I added the two files (one copied from SO and the other original erroneous file) to git and their git diff says: ```Binary files a.. and b.. differ```.

Answer (score 0):

You chose not to offer a
[reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Here is the code I'm running
which is intended to represent what you're running.
If there is some discrepancy, update the original
question to clarify the details.

---

```
import json
from io import StringIO

some_data = dict(a=1)
more_data = dict(b=2)
data = {"meta_data": some_data, "real_data": more_data}

file = StringIO()
json.dump(data, file)
file.seek(0)

d = json.load(file)
print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
```

output

```
{
    "meta_data": {
        "a": 1
    },
    "real_data": {
        "b": 2
    }
}
```

As is apparent, over the circumstances you have
described the JSON library does exactly what we
would expect of it.

EDIT

Your screenshot makes it pretty clear
that a bunch of ASCII NUL characters are appended
to the 1st file.
We can easily reproduce that `JSONDecodeError: Extra data`
symptom by adding a single line:

```
json.dump(data, file)
file.write(chr(0))
```

(Or perhaps `chr(0) * 80` more closely matches the truncated screenshot.)

If your file ends with extraneous characters, such as NUL,
then it will no longer be valid JSON and compliant
parsers will report a diagnostic message when they
attempt to read it.
And there's nothing special about NUL, as a simple
`file.write("X")` suffices to produce that same
diagnostic.

You will need to trim those NULs from the file's end
before attempting to parse it.
For best results, use UTF8 unicode encoding with no
[BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

---

Your editor should have settings for
switching to utf8.
Use `$ file foo.json` to verify encoding details,
and `$ iconv --to-code=UTF-8  < foo.json`
to alter an unfortunate encoding.

Comment: Hey, I chose and tried to provide parts of codes that should have reproduced the problem.. but as I said in my comment (involving ```git diff```), there maybe a more involved issue.. Should I remove the codes which do not seem to reproduce a problem, so that viewers may not get misled.

Answer (score -1):

You need to read the file, you can do both of these.

```
data = json.loads(open("data.json").read())
```

or

```
with open("data.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```